# using onscroll on an element that doesnt scroll

Tags: javascript

So I have an element that I want to be able to zoom in and out of using the scroll wheel on my mouse. I thought a good way to go about this would be something like this:

**JavaScript**:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container"),
    zoom = document.getElementById("zoom");
var x = 0, lastScrollTop = 0;
const zoomWidth = zoom.getBoundingClientRect().width;
// I want the container to be the one that is targeted because
// sometimes the zoom element will be offset horizontally by too much
container.onscroll = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
    x += (scrollTop < lastScrollTop ? 0.1 : -0.1);

    zoom.style.width = (zoomWidth * x) + "px";
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop <= 0 ? 0 : scrollTop;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="zoom"></div>
</div>
```

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ukr30oca/1/)

The only problem with this is that you can't detect whether or not the user is scrolling up or down (or detect if the scroll wheel is being used **at all** for that matter), when the element itself *doesn't scroll*.

So how do I go about zooming using the scroll wheel, on an element that doesn't actually scroll? Cheers.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event#Scaling_an_element_via_the_wheel

Answer (score 1):

There is an event called `wheel`

you can attached a wheel event listener on the element

```
el.addEventListener('wheel', function(event){
  //do your job here 
});
```

available properties in wheel event

```
    {
    altKey: false
    bubbles: true
    button: 0
    buttons: 0
    cancelBubble: false
    cancelable: true
    clientX: 345
    clientY: 154
    composed: true
    ctrlKey: false
    currentTarget: div
    defaultPrevented: false
    deltaMode: 0
    deltaX: -0
    deltaY: -125
    deltaZ: 0
    detail: 0
    eventPhase: 2
    fromElement: null
    isTrusted: true
    layerX: 89
    layerY: 61
    metaKey: false
    movementX: 0
    movementY: 0
    offsetX: 90
    offsetY: 62
    pageX: 345
    pageY: 154
    path: (5)[div, body, html, document, Window]
    relatedTarget: null
    returnValue: true
    screenX: 822
    screenY: 491
    shiftKey: false
    sourceCapabilities: null
    srcElement: div
    target: div
    timeStamp: 171662.21500000005
    toElement: div
    type: "wheel"
    wheelDelta: 150
    wheelDeltaX: 0
    wheelDeltaY: 150
    which: 0
    x: 345
    y: 154
}
```

property    `deltaX , deltaY` are sufficient for calculating

There is a nice example in [mdn check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event#Scaling_an_element_via_the_wheel)